# How to embed a Google Drive folder in a web page

Tags: html, google-drive-api, embed

I have a folder in Google Drive that I'd like to embed in my web page. I can't find an embed code or anything documented in Google Drive Help articles.

Comment: Is there a way to use `<embed>` to autosize the content better than an `<iframe>`?

Comment: For a better alternative (with ability to navigate to sub-folders & previewing of files), see this: https://medium.com/@thesumitsingh/how-to-embed-google-drive-folder-files-with-1-line-of-code-e445af55d8fd

Answer (score 110, accepted):

## Update

I just wrote a [blog post](https://mori.pages.dev/blog/embed-google-drive-folders) and created an embed code generator to make your life a bit easier.

---

1. Go to your Google Drive.
2. Right-click on the folder.
3. Select **Share**.
4. Open the **General access** drop-down menu.
5. Select **Anyone with the link** to publish your folder.
6. Click **Copy link** and then **Done**.
   You will get a URL like the following:
   [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/**1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa**?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa?usp=sharing)
   You can see your folder ID in bold: **1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa**
7. Google Drive folders can be embedded and displayed in `list` and `grid` views. Put the folder ID in one of the following `iframe` sources:

### List view

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

### Grid view

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I just tried this extensively. Nothing at all renders in my iframes. Google Docs has always seemed so close to be so much better than it is. Sigh. Even if I had to pay a little for a url that'd work, I'd consider it.

Comment: This solution is working for me, for some months now. It is true that the logged-in user must have view access to the folder to be listed.

Comment: This works well - is there a way to grab just the URL's?

Comment: This works well in latest firefox and chrome. Minor concern here is all the folder/doc links open in a separate window. Is there a way to browse drive folders within the same iframe?. is there a way we could use <base target="_parent" />?

Comment: I'm also interested in the same answer as @apremalal. Likely there is not going to be a happy answer as it seems that GDrive doesn't give even a ".." (back to parent) button in the view, so there would be no way to go back.

Comment: @Doc I used to get a blank `IFRAME` when I didn't have permission. I think it's better now, since a message appears saying **You need permission**. The embedded folder view also returns some buttons to help you **Request access** or **Change accounts**. Sadly, these buttons don't work inside an `IFRAME` (at least not with the version of Chrome I'm using). If your browser lets you open the frame in another tab, you can work around this. If you need to switch accounts to get access, the original embedded access won't switch, but you can use the tabbed-out one.

Comment: @Chema I just reviewed your suggested edit. You seem to have spent considerable time and effort on it, but [one does not simply change the intent of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194463), yet alone a highly upvoted one. IMO posting your own answer would be much better in this case.

Comment: @Siguza Will do (if I can find it somewhere), though could you clarify how did the intent change with my edit, exactly?  As I recall, I simply added the bit about including the domain in the URL, and clarified in which situations you would get a blank frame or a permission request.

Comment: @Chema This has been a much discussed topic, but roughly: the guidelines for editing answers are more strict than for questions, [even changing formatting is a delicate thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115). Your edit added new examples, new information and a new guiding section - all of which we cannot ad-hoc assume the author to have wanted to include. I think such an edit would have been fine on a wiki, but answers in Q&A aren't really that. I don't know if there's a source link to it, but you can see your edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15672277).

Comment: Thanks @Siguza!  Only because of your thoughtful comments did I realise that my edit had been rejected (a notification would've been nice), and that SA is, indeed, not a wiki, but a whole different kind of animal.  I won't bother trying to learn the psychology of it, though I now also understand why too often the top answer is obsolete.  The Community Wiki thing seems a step in the right direction to allow more prompt updates, if a small one.  Thanks again!

Comment: If I have 1000 files in the folder, it does not show up everything.

Comment: Is there a way to change the sorting order?

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm also interested whether it's possible to open documents within the same iframe.

Answer (score 27):

## Embedding a Google Drive directory in an IFRAME

Google Drive folders can be embedded and displayed in `list` and `grid` views (in which all you can do is click a file or folder to open it on a new tab).  To do so, simply replace *FOLDER-ID* and for private folders (as of 2022) *RESOURCE-KEY* with your own in:

**List view**

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&resourcekey=RESOURCE-KEY#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

or without specifying a mode, since list mode is the default:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&resourcekey=RESOURCE-KEY" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

**Grid view**

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&resourcekey=RESOURCE-KEY#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

### Obtaining your folder id

You can simply replace `drive/folders/` with `embeddedfolderview?id=` in a standard Drive sharing link.

The id is the hash (alphanumeric gibberish) after `folders/` in the URL of the folder.  You can see the URL in the address bar of your browser when you open the Drive folder.  The Resource Key you can find in the sharing link, after copying it.  For example, in:

```
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9s5Ht8qysnFMXhaZDFfQlJEalE&resourcekey=0-in7UrBAlXKTSN6poaUSl9g`
```

The Folder ID is `0B9s5Ht8qysnFMXhaZDFfQlJEalE` and the Resource Key is `0-in7UrBAlXKTSN6poaUSl9g`.

### Folder with G Suite/Google Apps domain

Since the introduction of the Resource Key parameter in 2022, and as of Jan 2023, embedding G Suite domain folders fails with a 403 Error ("We're sorry but you do not have access to this page.  That's all we know.").  The following is left just in case they fix it sometime.

If your folder is part of a Google Apps domain, you can add the domain to the URL to alleviate the permission problems (detailed further ahead):

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/a/MY.DOMAIN.COM/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

Just replace *MY.DOMAIN.COM* and *FOLDER-ID* with your own.

### Caveat with folders requiring permission

This technique works best for folders with public access. Folders that are shared only with certain Google accounts can cause trouble when you embed them this way, depending on which Google accounts are active on the user's browser:

1. If the user has not logged in to any Google account, then **nothing** appears in the frame.
2. If the user is logged onto an account without authorisation to access the folder, the frame will contain the message *You need permission*, with some buttons to *Request access* or *Switch accounts*, but if you click on this last, the frame blanks out.
3. If the user logs into an account without proper permissions, and later adds the authorised account, on loading the embedded Drive Google will resort to the first active account, and the user will see *You need permission*, unless...
4. If the URL contains a Google Suite domain, and the user is logged into that domain's account, the embedded view will work, *even if the user logged to another account first*.

The blank frames are because Google forbids embedding its login page in an IFRAME (presumably to prevent account stealing), via the `X-Frame-Options` header, which if set to `SAMEORIGIN` will cause any well-behaved browser to refuse to load the page if it's not in the same domain (v.g. `drive.google.com`).  You can see this in the developer console of your browser.

## TL;DR

To get a list or grid view of a Drive folder (in which all you can do is click a file or folder to open it on a new tab), use:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&resourcekey=RESOURCE-KEY#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

For a Google Suite/Apps Drive, the following is broken as of Jan 2023:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/a/MY.DOMAIN.COM/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

Replace *MY.DOMAIN.COM* and *FOLDER-ID* with your own; remove `#grid` to get a detailed file list.

For private folders, have your users log to the correct account before loading the page with the embedded folder; if the folder is in a Google Apps domain, you can add the domain to the URL.  Else, they must log into the authorised account before any other.

(this answer is an edit of Mori's, but it was rejected as it changed his *intent*, somehow)

Comment: Is there any way to get a carrousel (>) arrow key for enlarging images of the iframe?

Answer (score 5):

At the time of writing this answer, there was no method to embed which let the user navigate inside folders and view the files without her leaving the website (the method in other answers, makes everything open in a new tab on google drive website), so I made my own tool for it. To embed a drive, paste the iframe code below in your HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://googledriveembedder.collegefam.com/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&folderid=FOLDER_ID_WHIHCH_IS_PUBLICLY_VIEWABLE" style="border:none;" width="100%"></iframe>
```

In the above code, you need to have your own API key and the folder ID. You can set the height as per your wish.

**To get the API key:**

1.) Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ Create a new project.

2.) From the menu button, go to 'APIs and Services' --> 'Dashboard' --> Click on 'Enable APIs and Services'.

3.) Search for 'Google Drive API', enable it. Then go to "credentials' tab, and create credentials. Keep your API key unrestricted.

4.) Copy the newly generated API key.

**To get the folder ID:**

1.)Go to the google drive folder you want to embed (for example,  drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1v7cGug_e3lNT0YjhvtYrwKV7dGY-Nyh5u [this is not a real folder]) Ensure that the folder is publicly shared and visible to anyone.

2.) Copy the part after 'folders/', this is your folder ID.

Now put both the API key and folder id in the above code and embed.

**Note**:
This works **only for files and subfolders you actually uploaded in the GDrive folder, not the subfolders you add as 'shortcut'**. If a subfolder is displaying improperly, download it's contents and upload it to drive inside that specific folder. If you 'Move' folder within google drive, GDrive adds it as a 'shortcut'.

To hide the download button for files, add '&allowdl=no' at the end of the iframe's src URL.

I made the widget keeping mobile users in mind, however it suits both mobile and desktop. If you run into issues, leave a comment here.
I have attached some screenshots of the content of the iframe here.

[image: The file preview looks like this]
[image: The content of the iframe looks like this]

Comment: It only displays the text: "Browse files"

Comment: @Chips147 probably the API key or folder id is incorrectly copied. Or maybe the specific folder you are trying to display is not publicly viewable (sharing permissions-> anyone with link can view)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Note: all subfolders and files should be also open. Questions: 1) is there an open code for the project? 2) Can the developer contact me or my client? They want to ask for help with a similar task.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov the code isn't open. You can connect with me for specific help at studyforexams at gmail dot com

Comment: In this, I will expose my API key to everyone, isn't this a bad practice? [Securing an API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key)

Comment: @AnkitChauhan You can place security restrictions on your api key from GCP, which will make it safe. Even i thought about this earlier, but then i saw that on Google Drive, even google's key is exposed. (you can check the api calls Google Drive makes). They have protected it by adding domain restrictions. So if somebody else gets the key, they can't use it.

Answer (score 3):

For business/Gsuite apps or whatever they call them, you can specify the domain (had problem with 500 errors with the original answer when logged into multiple Google accounts).

```
<iframe 
  src="https://drive.google.com/a/YOUR_COMPANY_DOMAIN/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID" 
  style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"
>
</iframe>
```