# Google Sites HTML Iframe (not gadget)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm trying to embed a google drive folder inside my google site, but this folder will be shown only to some users. That is why I can't use Insert --> Drive --> Folder.

I found at this post [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website) that you can show a specift folder using a HTML Iframe and It works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to embed that iframe on my Google Site with no luck. I've tried 3 different ways:

### 1) Using a **HTML box** (Insert --> HTML box)

This return the follow: ***removing disallowed attribute src on tag iframe***

I used the exact same html code that works just fine

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B9xgK9AXrIuiMS0xNTQ5MzZjNy0xYTAxLTQzMjQtYWVkOS03M2Q3YWQxMzVhN2I#list" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

### 2) Using the HTML service (Google Apps Script)

I create a Google Script that goes like this:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello Stackoverflow</p>
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B9xgK9AXrIuiMS0xNTQ5MzZjNy0xYTAxLTQzMjQtYWVkOS03M2Q3YWQxMzVhN2I#list" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This only shows the "Hello stackoverflow" and space where the iframe should be.

### 3) Insert --> More gadgets --> Include Gadget (iframe)

This one works with the same url that I used in the other methods: https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B9xgK9AXrIuiMS0xNTQ5MzZjNy0xYTAxLTQzMjQtYWVkOS03M2Q3YWQxMzVhN2I#list

But this way is useless to me because I need to have control over which users can and can't see the Google Drive folder inside the Google Site.

**Notice that it has nothing to do with http or https or the shield button on Google Chrome, because I'm using a https url.**

Answer (score 1):

Try below Apps Script code

code.gs

```
    function doGet(e) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
    return template.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Web App Search Page')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=XXXXXXXXXX_FOLDERID_XXXXXX#list" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Deploy as the web app and use "exec" link

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sandbox and the different modes for HTML service we have?

```
   function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#sandbox_mode

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work, but first access the sharing settings of the folder and make sure "everyone with the link can access".

Then retry doing the Insert > Google Drive