# How to embed the 'Recent' folder from Google Drive in a website

Tags: html, google-drive-api, embed

I've successfully embedded a folder I've created into my website using the answer from here:
[How to embed a Google Drive folder in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website)

Now I'm trying to embed the 'Recent' view in Google Drive. Is there a way to do this? I thought perhaps the 'recent' view has a default Folder ID however have been unable to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recent view is actually a search query with the results rendered, it is not a folder you can grab.

It defaults to a 'last modified' view, which is the same order that [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) returns files. Knowing this, you can decide how many 'recent' files you want to display and retrieve that number of files to render simply by issuing the files.list query.

Comment: The documentation for files.list says nothing about the order of returned files. Is the default behaviour you mention guaranteed (in which case can it be documented), or is it a side effect?