# How do I make a link for google drive folder, for mobile users?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

> [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website) only give the answer for desktop users (and a link for desktop view); it doesn't provide a mobile solution.

Can I give a link so that mobile users can view the folder like, in the Drive app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the mobile URL of Google Drive and [How to embed a Google Drive folder in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website)

This is the solution:
https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile#folder/0B1iqp0kGPjWsNDg5NWFlZjEtN2IwZC00NmZiLWE3MjktYTE2ZjZjNTZiMDY2