# Navigate in embed Google Drive folders

Tags: html, google-drive-api, embed

I just followed this suggestion : [How to embed a Google Drive folder in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website) to make a drive folder embed on my website. It works very well.

The problem is that I cant navigate in folders or clicking on a file, staying on the website. When I click on anything, it opens a new windows who redirect to the real drive page.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to your question. I thought I should share my findings for now:
Here is the same question as yours and it wasn't answered for more than 3 years (maybe this suggests that there is no easy solution):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756696/navigating-google-folders-in-the-embeded-iframe
Here are some solutions from a third party: https://www.steegle.com/apps-script/google-drive-embed-gadget/live-examples#h.p_LwTzqrEqabQp

If you can find anything better, please let me know.