# Cannot embed Google Drive Files in an iframe

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I recently had a problem with the Google Drive API displaying my documents. We have developed a web application that is connecting to Google Drive accounts to retrieve a user's drive files, then display in an iframe the file using its embedUrl/alternateUrl.

This has worked fine for us in the past, but suddenly files other than Google Documents stopped displaying: html files, text files, doc files... even images!

The error I get is `Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_JkNS6Wu4b5R2c0YlJSN0oyQUE/edit?usp=drivesdk' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

I understand the error, it means that Google is preventing the display of documents outside of the Google domain, but the question is "why suddenly now", and how to circumvent it.

If someone stumbled upon the same issue and have found a solution, I'd be glad to hear.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: I've found the following questions on the topic, but no descriptions as to why it is no longer working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367610/showing-documents-from-google-drive-on-webpage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103154/how-can-i-embed-a-google-docs-collection-in-an-iframe

Comment: Same problem too. I'm trying to embed a PDF on my CMS, but no chances. I've tried to generate a public link to allow embeding, but the problem persists.

Comment: @jeferod83 did u find any solution for it. I need o use view link because i need download and print tools in the view

Answer (score 30):

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_JkNS6Wu4b5R2c0YlJSN0oyQUE/preview?usp=drivesdk
```

Use **preview** instead of **edit** in the URL. It will work.

Comment: Is there any way to have the whole UI Editor of Google? The preview works but I need the editor. It does work, though. It's just annoying to see the error in the inspection console, makes me think eventually it will fail.

Comment: t works with preview but in console is ugly red error  for same origin which google set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the following workaround showing the google drive files as webpage ressources
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

This means you have to extract the **[doc id]** from your url and change your link to:
http://www.googledrive.com/host/**[doc id]**

Please note: in this case the google drive controls are not shown.

Comment: googledrive.com/host/ID is deprecated as of August 31, 2015