# Displaying Google results in a frame

Tags: frames

Some time in the last year, a tool that I use no longer displays Google search results in one of its frames. I suspect that Google started using JavaScript code to hide itself, if it is being displayed in a frame, which is understandable for most uses.

However, this is a tool that only I use, so I'm not misrepresenting to anyone. I use this tool to research data. One frame has a form where I enter data that I find online. The other frame has the Google results and the pages they link to. I can see both the data form that I'm working on and the changing search/results side-by-side in one window.

I tried going to an older browser version, but I think they are using JavaScript.

Now I have to right-mouse click "open in a new tab" and then click to the new tab, and then close it, a lot of extra overhead when I'm trying to process this repetitive research over and over.

Any ideas? Confirmations as to what has changed? I suppose I could retrieve the page in PHP, strip out the part that hides the page and then put the page source in the other frame. A bit of a challenge for me.

Comment: I should add that I use the data form frame to automatically call Google search results, so I don't have to type into a search box. I click on one of a dozen links in the form form and the results frame loads the results (or the appropriate Wikipedia article, etc). I haven't been able to figure out how to the same using two browers in separate monitors.

Comment: I'm trying to get Google Search results to appear in an iframe as well, This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966476/google-search-results-in-iframe-alternative

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/web-search/?csw=1) probably explains why it stopped working, see the deprecation notice at the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google search results in iframe alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966476/google-search-results-in-iframe-alternative)