# parse an element from a hidden frame into a visible frame using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know a way to parse a DIV from an html frame into a visible frame using JavaScript?

For example, if I make an hidden frame of Google search results and  show on the visible frame only the search results element without the search box, menu tabs, etc.

Comment: You can't access the contents of cross-domain embedded documents.

Comment: I doubt you can place google search results in an iframe

Comment: check more http://stackoverflow.com/a/7966754/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [google search results in iframe alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966476/google-search-results-in-iframe-alternative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put google's website in an frame or iframe you'll get the javascript Exception with text: "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Google does not allow to put the site in an iframe.

To forbid your website in an iframe you can use code like this:

```
var inIframe = function() {
    return (top != self);
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (inIframe()) { throw new Error("Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."); }

    // load site
});
```